# Solving non-convex optimization problem using python

Tags: python, numpy, cvxpy, cvxopt

I need to maximize a two-variable non-convex function, which contains a log to the base 2.

I tried CVXPY but an error appears:

```
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules.
```

The function is like this:

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

x = cp.Variable(2, nonneg=True)
A=23
B=34
C=45
Ob=cp.Minimize(-cp.log(1 + x[0]/(A*x[1]+C))/np.log(2) - cp.log(1 + B*x[1])/np.log(2))
constraints = [0 <= x, x <= 1, cp.sum(x) == 1, x[0] >= x[1]]
prob = cp.Problem(Ob, constraints)
result = prob.solve()
```

where A, B, and C are just constants.

Should I use another python library to solve the problem and what is the DCP error?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, you are running into a fundamental limitation of that library, as it is made to only solve convex optimization problems and your problem is non-convex.

I suggest using [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) instead.

Comment: Is scipy.optimize suitable for Log functions because no mention for these in their page?

Comment: @learningstatistics it is completely general, so it works for all functions

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would you recommend a certain algorithm that best deal with this optimization problem.

Comment: @learningstatistics the default always worked for me, if optimization does not converge, retry with different starting values

Answer (score -1):

You can use Mathematica to solve the optimization problem.

```js
Clear["Global`*"];
(*Define the variables*)
vars = {x1, x2};

(*Define the constants*)
A1 = 23;
B1 = 34;
C1 = 45;

(*Define the objective function*)
objective = -Log[2, 1 + x1/(A1*x2 + C1)] - Log[2, 1 + B1*x2];

(*Define the constraints*)
constraints = {0 <= x1, x1 <= 1, 0 <= x2, x2 <= 1, x1 + x2 == 1, 
   x1 >= x2};

(*Solve the optimization problem*)
solution = NMinimize[{objective, constraints}, vars];

(*Display the result*)
solution //Print
```

```
{-4.18264, {x1 -> 0.5, x2 -> 0.5}}
```